# How to turn off "Your SIM played a tone" message on iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, ios

Each time when I get the message "Your SIM played a tone" if I don't respond instantly and close the option it gets stuck and my entire iOS 9.3.2 
doesn't respond. I have had this issue some ten times. How do I disable this?

Answer (score 1):

To disable the feature do the following:

Open Settings > Phone > SIM Applications then turn off the CallerXChange Service or anything similiar to that.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a fix for this.

Go to **Settings > Privacy > Location Services**, then scroll down for **System Services** and turn off **Location-Based iAds**.

Comment: Not working for me on iPhone 5S